# Link tag not working in React Router v6.7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

React router v6.7  does add /about to the end of the url but doesn't render the components. Normally putting the url does work though.

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Navbar(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <nav className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-${props.mode} bg-${props.mode}`}>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">{props.title}</Link>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">{props.aboutText}</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                                <Link className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" to="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Dropdown
                                </Link>
                                <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">Action</Link></li>
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">Another action</Link></li>
                                    <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                                    <li><Link className="dropdown-item" to="/">Something else here</Link></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link to="/" className="nav-link disabled">Disabled</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="form-check form-switch mx-3">
                            <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" onClick={props.toggleDarkMode} />
                            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Dark Mode</label>
                        </div>
                        <form className="d-flex">
                            <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
Navbar.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    aboutText: PropTypes.string
}

Navbar.defaultProps = {
    title: "Enter your Title",
    aboutText: "About"
}
```

App.js

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import About from './components/About';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import TextForm from './components/TextForm';

import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <TextForm />,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    element: <About />
  }
]);

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
  const toggleDarkMode = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setMode("dark");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#15181a";
      document.body.style.color = "white";
    }
    else {
      setMode("light");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.body.style.color = "black";
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar title="TextUtils" aboutText="About Us" mode={mode} toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Expectation:
Link to should render the component into the DOM without reloading.

Reality:
The url gets concatenated but the page actually doesn't render anything.

Comment: You don't appear to have actually defined any routes inside your app - you just have links, but don't specify anywhere what components should be rendered at those routes. I think you need to [have a closer look at the docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#adding-a-router).

Comment: I have added routes to App.js and imported NavBar.js into it to render do I have attached the App.js too. Do I need to add routes to NavBar.js too?

Comment: no you don't - thanks for editing, it wasn't clear that you had any such code. Particularly as you have a `<BrowserRouter>` inside `NavBar` which I don't believe is needed. Does the problem get fixed if you simply remove that? (I wish I had more experience with React Router - I've used it in one previous project but I'm not familiar at all with the newer v6 API, and the docs don't seem to be the clearest! [This page](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) though suggests that you don't need a `BrowserRouter` when you're already using `createBrowserRouter`.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So the thing is React Router v6.7 docs for getting started does not mention that the elements inside the:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<TextForm />} />
    <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
  </Route>
))
```

Would be rendered wherever the `<Outlet />` tag is.
So I made RootLayout page and put it inside that and everything works. Here is what it looks like.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function RootLayout() {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
    const toggleDarkMode = (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            setMode("dark");
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#15181a";
            document.body.style.color = "white";
        }
        else {
            setMode("light");
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.body.style.color = "black";
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar title="TextUtils" aboutText="About Us" mode={mode} toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} />
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<RouterProvider />` needs to wrap the `NavBar` component with `router` prop. [Check out the official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial).

What you're currently doing is wrapping the `Navbar` but you have provided no `router` instance. So it doesn't know the routes and which component to render when routes change.

Refactor App.js like this:

```
 <>
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
<Navbar title="TextUtils" aboutText="About Us" mode={mode} toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} />
    </RouterProvider>
    </>
```

And remove `RouterProvider` parent component from `Navbar`

Comment: RouterProvider is a self closing element as far as I know